# smooth transition when div float moves, jquery ui

Tags: jquery-ui, html, jquery-animate

lets say I have a grid of divs caused by duplicated one `display: inline` div and setting it as `float: left` right?

`[1] [2] [3]`

`4] [5] [6]`

`[7] [8] [9]`

now, lets say I remove one of them with jquery `.hide()` 
they all scoot over to take the place of the floating div that left. And especially in the case of changing rows like if 3 was gone, and [4] and [7] are promoted to a higher line.

So how do i apply some sort animated effect to this change? It would be nice if it could just animate their in a straight line, or if it faded out in one location and faded in in another.

PS my actual application does not remove the div, it resize them to be taller, thus displacing divs to the right and below.

Help!

Thanks ::]

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? Coz I have got one :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ha28t/

Check this fiddle where I have chained the effects that you have asked for. When certain divs go missing, I animate the transition so that the divs do not just "rush-in" but rather "ease-in" over 500ms.

```
jQuery('#header ul li:nth-child(2)').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();   
  jQuery('div.piece').css("border","solid 1px black");
  jQuery('div.piece:not(.photo)').css("border","none");
  jQuery('div.piece:not(.photo)').animate({ width: -2 }, 
    { duration: 500, queue: false });
  jQuery('div.photo').animate({ width: 98 }, 
    { duration: 500, queue: false });
});
```

Hope this helps!